# How can I always choose the last column in a csv table that's updated monthly?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

Automating small business reporting from my Quickbooks P&L. I'm trying to get the net income value for the current month from a specific cell in a dataframe, but that cell moves one column to the right every month when I update the csv file.

For example, for the code below, this month I want the value from Nov[0], but next month I'll want the value from Dec[0], even though that column doesn't exist yet.

Is there a graceful way to always select the second right most column, or is this a stupid way to try and get this information?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


nov = -810
dec = 14958
total = 8693
d = {'Jan': [50], 'Feb': [70], 'Total':[120]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can reference the last or second-to-last row or column.

```
d = {'Jan': [50], 'Feb': [70], 'Total':[120]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
x = df.iloc[-1,-2]
```

This will select the value in the last row for the second-to-last column, in this case 70. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use the full file, @VincentRupp's answer will get you what you want.

But if you only plan to use the values in the second right most column ***and you can infer what it will be called***, you can tell `pd.read_csv` that's all you want.

```py
import pandas as pd  # 1.5.1


# assuming we want this month's name
# can modify to use some other month
abbreviated_month_name = pd.to_datetime("today").strftime("%b")

df = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.csv", usecols=[abbreviated_month_name])

print(df.iloc[-1, 0])
```

### References

- [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
- [`strftime` cheat-sheet](https://strftime.org/)

Comment: I like this extra step of automation very much. :)